# MODx: отправка информации из формы на новую страницу

Tags: веб-программирование, cms, modx

Нужно реализовать отправку формы не на email, а создавать новый ресурс с полученными данными из формы. Подскажите куда копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будем считать, что у Вас **revo**.
Использовать следует процессор `resource/create`

```
$parent = 9999; // id родительского ресурса (куда будем создавать ресурс)

/* Получаем */
$pagetitle = "Получаем заголовок"; // $_POST['pagetitle'];
$content = "Получаем контент"; // $_POST['content'];

/* Создаём новый ресурс */
$response = $modx->runProcessor('resource/create', array(
        'pagetitle' => $pagetitle,
        'content' => $content,
        'published' => 1,
        'parent' => $parent));
if ($response->isError()) {
    return $modx->error->failure($response->getMessage());
}

$newResource = $response->response['object'];

/* Очищаем кэш */
$modx->cacheManager->refresh();
return;
```